# ASP.net Loading Partial View with Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

Actually I was working with the kendo widgets.
I have loaded a partial view '**viewport**' inside **_Layout** to ajax load the other views inside the **viewport.**
I have included these scripts inside **viewport**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.918/jquery.min.js")"></script>
```

and as per the telerik documentation,

> The widget object is undefined after loading a page through AJAX
>   Usually caused when the page loaded via AJAX contains a script
>   reference to jQuery. When jQuery is re-initialized, all jQuery-based
>   data attributes are cleared, including the data("kendoWidget")
>   attribute that holds the Kendo UI widget object.

I tried to load the script inside the _Layout but it is not working.
How can it be Solved?

Comment: Is this the error 'JavaScript error that Kendo widgets are unavailable or undefined'?

Comment: Putting the scripts in the main view should not be a problem and would be preferred. Perhaps its the order in which you are loading them.

Comment: Actually there is no error.
When i load the scripts in the main view it doesnot work for the kendowidgets in the partial view. 
So I have loaded the kendo in the viewport where other views are loaded, it works perfect for the first time but when the viewport is again loaded, the script is loaded again and the jQuery is re-initialized which is the only problem.

Comment: I need a solution to load the jQuery only once in the viewport

Answer (score 0):

Please Include the script as below . But done it on the View page Which is loaded inside of the 
viewport.

Exaple : If you load the XXX page in viewport means. Then you have to mention the script in XXX page.

While loading the View From AJAX These kind of problem will occurs. Please mention that script only in the XX page with render in Viewport page.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.918/jquery.min.js")"></script>
```